# Codeigniter Refresh Div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I can't understand how to refresh data in div using jQuery, i know how it looks, but I don't know how to include it in my code.

**This is my controller:**

```
$data['chats'] = $this->core_model->getLastChats();
$this->loadTemplate('pages', 'index_view', $data);
```

**This is my view:**

```
public function getLastChats()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->limit(150);
    $this->db->order_by('c_date', 'DESC');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.u_id = chat.c_author');
    $query = $this->db->get('chat');

    return $query->result();
}
```

**And this is my view:**

```
<?php foreach($chats as $chat) { ?>
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
            <img class="media-object" style="width: 32px;" src="<?php echo $chat->u_avatar; ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h5 class="media-heading"><strong><?php echo $chat->u_name.' '.$chat->u_surname; ?></strong></h5>
            <?php echo $chat->c_message; ?><br />
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: PHP is loaded before the page, if you want to read data and display it on page you'll have to use XMLHttpRequest (XHR) to retrieve the required data in the background.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can You give me any example?

Comment: Take a look at this function, think how can you use the data retrieved in your site: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but since there is no answer to this basic question, I decided to answer it.

First, to get data from DB using jQuery, should call Ajax in your view.

So you can add the following javascript code in your view including div you want to show data.

Or you can add an additional js file.

your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="your_jsfile.js"></script>
```

And your_jsfile.js:

```
$(function() {
    
    ......
    var controller_function_url = site_url + 'your_controller/your_function'
    $.post(controller_function_url, function(resp){
        resp = JSON.parse(resp);
        var HTML = "";
        if(resp.status){
             for(I = 0; I < resp.body.chat.length; i++){
                 var item = resp.body.chat[i];
                 HTML += "<div class="media">";
                 html += "<div class="media-left">";
                 HTML += "<img class='media-object' style='width: 32px;' src='" + item['u_avatar'] + "'></div>";
                 HTML += "</div>"
                 ...............
             }

             $(your_parent_div).html(html);
        }
       
    });
    
    ........
});
```

your controller:(calling by ajax)

```
   public function your_function(){
        $data['chats'] = $this->core_model->getLastChats();
        $resp['status'] = true;
        $resp['body'] = $data;
        echo json_encode($resp);
    }
```

your initial controller(to show view)

```
   $data['chats'] = array();//empty array
   $this->loadTemplate('pages', 'index_view', $data);
```

This way you display an empty list on the initial load of the page.

As soon as the page is loaded, we get a list of data from the DB by an ajax call and display it instead of an empty list.

You can keep the list up to date by calling this ajax call whenever a refresh is needed.